# Mass density written in terms of expansion scalar

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, black-holes

The expansion scalar $\theta$ characterizes the geodesic congruence, this is quite standard and one famous reference that can be read is the *[Black Hole Mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521537800)* book by Eric Poisson.

In a paper [2111.05151](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.05151v3.pdf) that I'm reading, I've encountered an expression (equation (77) in the paper) where the mass density is written in terms of the expansion scalar. However, I'm not familiar with any resources that explicitly show how the mass density and the expansion scalar are related. In the paper, the relation between them is written in the specific case where everything has already been calculated. So, I do not know the general expression how they are related.

For example, the general expression for the expansion scalar $\theta$ is

$$\theta = \nabla_\mu k^\mu$$

where $k^\mu$ is the tangent vector. For the mass density $\mu$, what is the expression of it written in terms of the expansion scalar $\theta$?

Take note, in the paper, $\theta$ is written in two forms as $\theta_+$ and $\theta_-$ which are the outgoing and ingoing expansion scalar, but this doesn't really deviate from my original question.